# Dependencies of installed packages

Tags: package

Is there any way to see what dependencies has a package installed? In other words what other packages were installed with the first one?

Comment: AFAIK it's one of the features that Stefan Monnier wants to have implemented in `package.el`.  See [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/176518).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see what dependencies a package *has* by opening the `*Packages*` menu with `M-x list-packages`. Then navigate to your package of interest and hit `RET`.
This will display a buffer describing the package, which includes a list of dependencies.

There's no way of knowing which of these packages were actually installed as dependencies, and which were manually installed by you. Though there's been talk of implementing that in the dev list.

Comment: Where can I found the Packages menu?

Comment: @Adam edited in

Answer (score -1):

```
(let ((desc (assoc '{YOUR_PAcKAGE} package-archive-contents)))
  (if desc
      (-map (lambda (elem) (car elem))
            (aref (cadr desc) 4))))
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit from a bit of additional commentary.

Comment: Not the least of it being that it depends on dash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as I am a newbie I don't really understand it.